# how to print matching lines using a query file

Tags: text

I'm newbie programming and need an script that read the entries of one text "file1" and find these entries in another "file2" then, when one it find one entry, the whole line should be printed in "file" however, I don't even know how to star.

I have tryed to summarized the idea here:

“File1” - master
File1   string  string  string
File2   string  string  string
File3   string  string  string
File4   string  string  string
File5   string  string  string

“File2” - query
File2
File4

“File3” - output
File2   string  string  string
File4   string  string  string

I really appreciate your help

Thanks
Victor